# How to use foreign key in two tables based on a flag column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I have a parent table `Tree` and two child tables `Post` and `Department`.

Based on the `Flag` column this relation must be set.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. SQL Server does not support conditional foreign key, nor does any other rdbms (that I know of, at least).

Comment: This smells like EAV design, you really want to avoid those on relational databases, at least of you plan on using them to enforce consistency on entities.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with foreign keys. You could implement a trigger which would check for the `ReferenceID` presence either on the `Post` or on the `Department` table based oh the `Flag` column.

Although the best approach would be to change your design to have 2 nullable columns as follows, and ensuring only one of them has a value:

```
CREATE TABLE Tree (
    ID Integer NOT NULL,
    PostID Integer REFERENCES Post(ID),
    DepartmentID Integer REFERENCES Department(ID),
    Flag INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```